# How to find mean and standard deviation based on a given confidence interval?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

If a 95% confidence interval for a population mean ranges from 200 to 240 (that is, LCL=200 and UCL=240). Then, the computed numerical values of sample mean, $\bar{x}$, and sample standard deviation must have been:

a) we cannot tell from the given information

b) $\bar{x}$ = 220 and s=20

c) $\bar{x}$ = 220 and s=51.020

d) $\bar{x}$ = 220 and s=121.041

Comment: (-1) You didn't tell us what you know about sampling distribution, confidence interval and estimation, and you didn't bother reformulating your homework so that it could still be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Endpoints for a 95% CI are $\bar{x}-1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\bar{x}+1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Do you have enough information from the question to say what $\bar{x}$ and s are?